# How to protect admin javascript file?

Tags: javascript, apache, file-access

I have a javascript file for admin page only in my site. How to do that, the file was available only for admins. Checking roles performed by cookies. Maybe some sort of a check on the server? Server apache.

ps: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What exactly does the Javascript file do?  Sorry, I couldn't quite get what you were doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you check cookies from Javascript code [it is possible to check] but the JS will still get downloaded on client computer. I think you want such that no other than admin can download the file. If that is the case, then better use .htaccess or web.config file to resrtict folder which contain admin specific files for proper authentication.

in a tricky solution you can use URL Rewriting as well to prevent file download unless your PHP or server side code verify the user.